# Building binary socket .NET server: custom vs. SignalR vs XSockets vs WebSocket4Net?

Tags: .net, sockets, websocket

I need to build a server + client lib to request data from my [TimeSeriesDb database](http://code.google.com/p/timeseriesdb/), and there are many different socket and websocket libraries available for .NET, plus I could do my own implementation. Hence - can really use an advise on how to proceed.

I found [SuperSocket](http://supersocket.codeplex.com/) and [WebSocket4net](http://websocket4net.codeplex.com/) that is based on it, [XSockets](http://xsockets.net/), and [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR). There is also [Microsoft's WebSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implementation that is coming out with .NET 4.5 that might make others obsolete.

Yet, WebSockets are optimized for the web & realtime updates, rather than binary request responses I need, as the client is also a .NET lib that is not in the browser.

Details:

Both the db request and response are in binary:

**Client:** Get data for given params (a block of binary data)

**Server:** Starts sending a stream of data (as binary blocks), where the client could stop the transmission at any moment.

I am targeting .NET 4, so TPL Tasks might benefit with async capabilities.

Nice to have: stream multiplexing, where more than one request/response could go over the same connection (one block for each response in turn). I am not sure if this is needed, or if multiple connections would work better.

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets have binary type of data using opcode of %x2 based on official document [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-27).

As well WebSockets does implements framing for each data message it sends. For small packets it will be reasonable overhead of traffic.

If there is no plans for future support of connection to your database from front-end. Then I can't see why you would use WebSockets. It is more complicated then pure binary communication, and you will have to implement or use ready solution for WebSockets.
I beleive it is much efficient for memory and processing of packets to use pure TCP Sockets with Binary serialization. I would recommend to have a look in [Google Protocol Buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview), and check [.Net implementation](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).

That will allow you to pack your message data in nice way, and will add ability to communicate with other applications in future that implements this protocol as well.
As well if you are building Data Protocol into database, it would be much better to create handshake with selecting of Data Protocols, and then server will use one of available implementations that Client is preferring to communicate by.

You might be interested as well in using build-in Serialization functionality in .Net.